# EditText position within a Layout shifting

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following requirement:

> i> Consider a layout tab_container of height 40 dp.
>
> ii> The layout is divided into two equal individual parts in a
>   horizontal manner.
>
> iii>Within each individual layout , there is a TextView and EditText

The issue , for example , I enter a value 3 on edit_text_1 and then tap on edit_text_2 and enter 222, both the layouts shifts a bit (right or left) . 
This issue occurs when value is entered on edit_text_2 and edit_text_1 is tapped.

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_container"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_view_1"
                        style="@style/button_text_style_white_hdpi"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.6"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Sample"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        continental:typeface="roboto_bold" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edit_text_1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.4"
                        android:background="@color/White"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="3"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textIsSelectable="false"
                        android:textSize="14sp" >

                        <requestFocus />
                    </EditText>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_view_2"
                        style="@style/button_text_style_white_hdpi"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.6"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Sample2"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                         />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edit_text_2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.4"
                        android:background="@color/White"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="3"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textIsSelectable="false"
                        android:textSize="14sp" >


                        <requestFocus />
                    </EditText>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: I have just tried your layout without the style and typeface, and I cannot replicate the problem.

Comment: The first thing I would try would be to correct the parameters of `linear_layout_1` and `linear_layout_2`. If you're using `weights` to specify the `width` of those two `layouts` you should set `android:layout_width="0dp"` (instead of `wrap_content`) for both of them.